# How to extract data AFTER 1st hyphen and before 3rd hyphen in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a requirement, Where i have a column value like `STEP_D1_DEVTS_MN_PQ_LS`

I want the value after 1st underscore and before 3rd underscore and then get the replace the underscore  with hypen like below

`D1-DEVTS`.

Can some one please help me out here ?

I tried `SUBSTR` and `INSTR` that did not help me out.

Comment: Take a look at regular expressions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another is to use `SUBSTR` + `INSTR` (along with `REPLACE`, of course):

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select 'STEP_D1_DEVTS_MN_PQ_LS' from dual)
  3  select
  4    replace(substr(col,
  5                   instr(col, '_', 1, 1) + 1,                          --> start after the 1st underscore
  6                   instr(col, '_', 1, 3) - instr(col, '_', 1, 1) - 1   --> take everything that's between 1st and 3rd underscore
  7                  ), '_', '-') result                                  --> replace _ with -
  8  from test;

RESULT
--------------------
D1-DEVTS

SQL>
```

Comment: Thank you, It is working for this respective value, We have some values like Step_D1_DEVMS, STEP_T1_DEV2MS_TST. I tried using the same query and it showing null

Comment: You're welcome. You said that you need the string between the 1st and the 3rd underscore. If there's no 3rd underscore, well - it won't work (as you noticed) :) I presume you made it work, after all. If so, I'm glad if it helped.

Answer (score 1):

One option would be using concurrent `regexp_substr` expressions with a `replace`

```
with t(str) as
(
 select 'STEP_D1_DEVTS_MN_PQ_LS' from dual   
)    
select replace(regexp_substr(str,'[^_]+[_]',1,2)||regexp_substr(str,'[^_]+',1,3),'_','-') 
    as "Result String"
  from t;

Result String
-------------
D1-DEVTS
```

Comment: Thank you, It is working for this respective value, We have some values like Step_D1_DEVMS, STEP_T1_DEV2MS_TST. I tried using the same query and it showing null.

Comment: @KrupalPatel you're welcome. `Step_D1_DEVMS` gives `D1-DEVMS`, and `STEP_T1_DEV2MS_TST` gives `T1-DEV2MS` as result.

Comment: @KrupalPatel btw, if we change(shift left by one underscore) the manner of extracting, it's easier [to get](https://rextester.com/PCQF4738) the substrings by only one `regexp_substr` for each substring.

Comment: @KrupalPatel does prompt response mean comment response ? I realized that the other answer gives null for `Step_D1_DEVMS`, doesn't it?